# How to prove that $L = \{{a^{n} b^{n} c^{j} | n,j \geq 0}\}$ is a CFL?

Tags: context-free, pumping-lemma

In the text of my book it says that this language is context-free so I tried to prove that the conditions of the Pumping Lemma are fulfilled.

If, for example, I take the word
$aaabbbc$

I can divide it like this:

$u = ε, v = a, x = a, y = ab, z = bbc$

So the conditions:
$|vy| > 0$
$|vxy| <= p$ (if I consider p = 3)
are satisfied.

I have to prove that $uv^{i}xy^{i}z$ still belongs to the language.

But for $uv^{2}xy^{2}z$ I will have a string of the type:

$aa a abab bbc$
That should not belong to the language...

I'm probably missing something.

Comment: Why don't you just write down the trivial grammar?

Comment: This will give you no information on whether your language is context-free, but let's assume you want to apply the pumping lemma on $aaabbbc$ for the sake of it. Who tells you that the pumping length for the language is at least $3$ (the pumping lemma only guarantees that such a $p$ **exists**)? Also why do you choose that particular decomposition (again, the pumping lemma only tells you that **some** decomposition **exists**)? For example the decomposition $u=aa$, $v=a$, $x=\varepsilon$, $y=b$, $z=bbc$ works just fine.

Comment: @gnasher729 you are right hahah but I would like to understand better, thank you anyway

Comment: @Steven My doubt arises from the fact that when we prove that a language is not CF precisely we use the pumping lemma, e.g. on the language $L = {a^{n} b^{n} c^{n} | n>0}$ we prove that it is not CF by finding cases where the number of letters does not remain the same (e.g. by pumping only one of the letters). 
So if I had not known that $L = {a^{n} b^{n} c^{j} | n,j > 0}$ was CF then I would have tried to prove that for a given p there is a case where the pumped part is 'ab' and the string no longer belongs to L. 

But I probably keep missing some definition....

Comment: The pumping lemma can only be used to prove that a language is not CF. But even in that case, finding a case where the pumping lemma fails **for a fixed value of $p$** is useless, since the pumping lemma only tells you that **some value of $p$ exists**). To argue that the pumping lemma fails you need to be able to handle an arbitrarily large value of the pumping length $p$. Usually you do that choosing a word $w$ to be decomposed as a function of $p$. Similarly, you don't get to chose one particular decomposition of $w$, but you need to argue that no possible decomposition of $w$ works.

Comment: @Steven So then, if I understand correctly, we cannot prove that a language is CF with the pumping lemma because we do not know p and therefore it is not enough to find a case, with p fixed, for which the conditions are not satisfied. 

However, for example when we prove that $L = {a^{n} b^{n} c^{n} | n > 0}$ is not CF and we use the pumping lemma to prove it, only in this case we put all possible cases and whatever the string to be pumped, the final string will never belong to the language.

Answer (score 2):

Proving that the pumping lemma (for context free languages) holds for some language $L$ provides no information on whether $L$ is context-free (since the pumping lemma is just a necessary condition).

One way to prove that a language $L$ is context free is that of showing a context-free grammar that generates $L$. Here is a possible grammar for your particular language:
$$
S \to \varepsilon \mid X \mid C \mid XC \\
X \to ab \mid aXb \\
C \to c \mid cC 
$$

Comment: @Steven Thank you for your answer, but I cannot understand why if we find a string that does not fulfil the conditions of the pumping lemma then this is not enough to say that the language is not CF, since it is a necessary condition shouldn't it apply to all strings?

Comment: If you find a string for which the pumping lemma fails (i.e., the hypotheses are satisfied but the thesis is not), that is indeed a proof that the language **is not** context free. However if you are trying prove that the language **is** context free (as for the title of your question, and as is the case for $L$) then showing that the pumping lemma holds is useless. In your case $L$ is context free and hence you won't be able to find any example where the pumping lemma fails. In my comment to your question I highlighted why your decomposition does not show that the pumping lemma fails for $L$.

Comment: @Steven Thank you again for the clarification, and I had also thought of that way of dividing the string, but what I wonder is, should the string belong to the language whichever way we divide it? If indeed the language is context-free?

Comment: No. If the language is context free then, for any **sufficiently long** word $w$, there exists **some way** to decompose it such that all "pumped" versions of such a decomposition belong to the language. This does not need to hold for all possible decompositions (only one is enough). Look at the universal and existential quantifiers in the statement of the pumping lemma (and at their order).

Comment: @Steven Ok now everything is clearer, the problem is that I thought it had to apply to all possible decompositions, I thank you for your time.